# syntax mysql/php error

Tags: php, mysql

I really can't understand why this statement is wrong

```
$uname=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$str="select * from account where username='".$uname."' and password='".$pass."'";
echo $str;
echo "\n";
$str=mysql_real_escape_string($str);
$result=mysql_query($str) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $str);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

It shows me:

```
select * from account where username='negin'and password='parsa' Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'negin\'and password=\'parsa\'' at line 1 with query select * from account where username=\'negin\'and password=\'parsa\'
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are so last year....PDO PDO PDO

Comment: `ext/mysql` is officially deprecated. Please use mysqli or PDO, and please also use prepared statements and placeholders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` **on the parameters**, no on the whole query. You are escaping the single quotes so the query goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Use in this way**

```
$uname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$str="select * from account where username='".$uname."' and password='".$pass."'";

$result=mysql_query($str) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $str);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have problems running it like that as well, the issue is in the `mysql_real_escape_string()` section

```
//Change
$str="select * from account where username='".$uname."' and password='".$pass."'";

//To
$str="select * from account where username='".mysql_real_escape_string($uname)."' and password='".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the whole $str. It also escapes the single quotes which you have manually added inorder to insert the variables,. thus leading to errors.

Try this way.

```
$uname=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

$str="select * from account where username='".$uname."' and password='".$pass."'";
echo $str;
echo "\n";
//$str=mysql_real_escape_string($str);
$result=mysql_query($str) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $str);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```